# read a text line from a data file in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a series of txt files filled of intergers and double data,but in each file I have the first line as shown:

```
    X   Y
1   67.944  3.796
2   265.140 5.380
3   233.250 5.667
4   512.333 6.100
5   585.611 6.019
6   98.674  7.065
7   155 6
8   308 6.583
9   496.357 6.714
10  533.242 8.113
11  479.679 9.071
12  623 9.286
13  16.224  9.914
14  280.420 9.700
15  206.750 11.833
16  248.308 12.308
17  83.940  13.100
18  324 12.583
19  369.056 13.204
20  445.286 13
21  140.900 13.460
22  168.278 13.833
23  401.143 14.036
```

so as you can see I have this slash and X Y written in each file with 3 coloumns,I'm trying to read it with the following code I'm not able:

```
/* reading the data from the measurement file */
for(line=0;line< 1260;line++)
{
    if(line == 0)
        fscanf(measure_file,"%*d\n");
    else
        fscanf(measure_file,"%d\t%le\t%le\n",&n[line],&x[line],&y[line]);
}
```

maybe I'm doing something wrong in  if(line == 0)
                       fscanf(measure_file,"%*d\n");
anyone can help please ??

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `fscanf(f, "%*d\n");`, but it's certainly wrong. Why don't you just ignore the first line completely, by doing  simple `fgets()` **before** the loop?

Comment: Ignore first line fully or scan these into any two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
       char header[30];
       fgets(header, sizeof(header), measure_file);
       for(line=0;line< 1260;line++) {
           if (fscanf(measure_file, "%d\t%le\t%le\n", &n[line], &x[line], &y[line]) != 3)
               break;
           // ... 
       }
```

Comment: this worked thank youuuu you saved my life ;)  char header[30];
       fgets(header, sizeof(header), measure_file);
  /* reading the data from the measurement file */
for(line=0;line< 1260;line++)
   {
     if(line == 0)
     fscanf(measure_file,"%*d\n");/*%*d\n*/
     else
     fscanf(measure_file,"%d\t%le\t%le\n",&n[line],&x[line],&y[line]);